# Converting a DataTable value to a Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, datatable

I am trying to convert a DataTable value to a specified generic type but I'm getting an error.

I have already programmed a similar function which works fine. It returns a string that I can use to put in a TextBox or a ComboBox and I'm trying to modify it to change it's return type. Here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Value from a DataTable
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of Value to get from the DataTable : int | Single | string | double</typeparam>
/// <param name="columnName">Name of the column in the DataTable</param>
/// <param name="table">The DataTable</param>
/// <returns>Get the string value to put in a Textbox</returns>
public static string getDB<T>(string columnName, DataTable table, int index = 0)
{
    bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(table.Rows[index][columnName]));
    return (!isEmpty) ? Convert.ToString(Convert.ChangeType(table.Rows[index][columnName], typeof(T))) : "";
}
```

I have done this simple change to alter it's return type but I am unsure how to properly cast my object so that I convert my DataTable to a generic type.

```
public static T getDBSpecifiedType<T>(string columnName, DataTable table, int index = 0)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(table.Rows[index][columnName], typeof(T));
}
```

> **Error:** 
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The function seems simple to my eye and the error message is not complicated I am just missing something to get my function to work.

Thanks for any help, Simon

Comment: Whats the error message? Perhaps you aren't checking if the index and/or column name exist first?

Comment: The error is in the getDBSpecifiedType Function : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up using by searching for more answers on SO is the following:

```
public static Nullable<T> getDBSpecifiedType<T>(string columnName, DataTable table, int index = 0)
{
    if (getDB<T>(columnName, table, index) != String.Empty)
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(table.Rows[index][columnName], typeof(T));

    return null;
}
```

By calling my original function I was able to determine if the DataTable value is empty and return null (I am using Nullables since the default value of a string compared to a double is different for example). If it's not empty I am able to cast it to the generic type and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

This model of `T` type casting worked for me as well:

```
public static T getDBSpecifiedType<T>(string columnName, DataTable table, int index = 0)
{
     return (T) table.Rows[index][columnName];
}
```

But, you can use [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert dataTable column types.
The [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) provides strongly-typed access to each of the column values in the specified row.

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row,  string columnName)
```

And for example you can use that this model:

```
foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable())                        
{
    users.Add(new User(row.Field<int>("Id")) { Name = row.Field<string>("Name") });       
};
```

[Microsoft Reference Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs)